# FTP transfer by cron

Tags: ftp, cron

i need to have ftp transfer using ncftp, with crond that execute it. but it failed to work...

i tried with ncftp and ncftpput, and scripts works ok if  start them manually, but failed when cron executed them.....

simple example is

```
[root@myserver sbin]# more mik.sh 
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/ncftpput -u remoteserver -p123 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /backup /tmp/backup.6558/*
[root@myserver sbin]#
```

cron is defined like

```
* * * * * /usr/local/sbin/mik.sh
```

can you tell me where i'm wrong please....

tnx in adv!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i make it. so, cron looks like:

```
0       2       *       *       *       /usr/local/sbin/mik.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and in mik.sh i defined FULL path of ncftp, like `/usr/local/bin/ncftp`

tnx anw!