# copy Files from FTP to server on linux

Tags: linux, ftp, files

I have access to an FTP account where new files will be uploaded every day  of different sizes from 5MB to 500MB. My requirement is the files have to be copied to my server every day. Can this be done?

Comment: "Copied to the server"?

Comment: How much access do you have? How is the server connected to the FTP server ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your server is running linux, my choice would be to use [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/)  & stick it in a [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to run daily.

Much like [this question here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/163786/ncftp-ftp-transfer-by-cron)

Answer (score 0):

check out  `lftp`

it can be easily scripted

Answer (score 0):

My choice is to use wget in this way:

```
wget -r ftp://username:password@domain.com/directory/
```

I used it and it was okay.